# Is there any way to perform GROUP BY operation in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, graphql-js, graphql-java

I need to group data in a table by using a particular field in the table. And couldn't find GROUP BY feature in GraphQL. Is there any way to achieve that ?

Current Format :

```
[
   {
      "my_state":"karnatak",
      "from_state":"kerala",
      "route":"wayanad"
   },
   {
      "my_state":"karnatak",
      "from_state":"kerala",
      "route":"Mangalore"
   },
   {
      "my_state":"karnatak",
      "from_state":"kerala",
      "route":"Palakkad"
   },
   {
      "my_state":"karnatak",
      "from_state":"tamilnadu",
      "route":"hosure"
   },
   {
      "my_state":"karnatak",
      "from_state":"tamilnadu",
      "route":"selam"
   },
   {
      "my_state":"karnatak",
      "from_state":"tamilnadu",
      "route":"chennai"
   }
]
```

Required Format:

```
from_state: "karnatak",
  route: [
    {
      route: "chennai"
    },
    {
      route: "selam"
    },
    ............
  ]
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample response format that you need?

Comment: Added sample response. Any GROUP BY operation sample is fine

Answer (score 2):

[GraphQL is a *query language for APIs*](https://graphql.org/) and it does not really "contain features" like GroupBy, Count, Sort, etc. Those features or queries have to be implemented in the server (GraphQL API) and it leaves you a couple of options:

- If you own the API(server) then you would have to create your own "GroupBy query" that would allow you to fetch the data the way you would like.
- If you are just using the API you can use the schema documentation to search if there is a query format that satisfies your need.
- You can also make your own groupBy function after fetching the data, there's some good examples [in these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890276/3708153).